# Unable to authorize Azure Subscription for use within YAML based pipeline

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

An Azure DevOps YAML based pipeline has been created from scratch and requires the use of Azure Subscription. The Subscription value has been stored within Key Vault and then linked to the Variable Group. Pipeline has unobtrusive access to both Variable Group and linked Key Vault. However the pipeline execution fails with the error that the pipeline does not have access to the required subscription. When the Subscription value is moved to the Variable Group the issue is still present. When the Subscription value is declared as a pipeline variable the issue is gone. The click on the Authorize button next to the error does not help with the issue.

```
- stage: 'DeployDevelopment'
  displayName: ''
  dependsOn: Build
  jobs:
  - deployment: DeployDevelopment
    pool:
      vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
    environment: Development
    variables:
    - group: Secrets
    - group: Release
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
            displayName: ''
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: '$(ConnectedServiceName)'
              appType: 'webAppLinux'
              WebAppName: '$(DevEnvironemntWebAppName)'
              packageForLinux: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/app/s'
              RuntimeStack: 'NODE|10-lts'
              StartupCommand: '$(StartupCommand)'
              WebConfigParameters: '-Handler iisnode -NodeStartFile server.js -appType node'
              AppSettings: '-WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION 10.12.0'
```

[image: Error.]

[image: Error after the click on Authorize resources button has been performed.]

Comment: Azure service connection needs at least Get and List management permissions on the vault for secrets. Do you select these two permissions in access policies?

Comment: The required permissions are granted. However, even when the Subscription value is not stored within the Key Vault, but within Variable Group only, the issue persists.

Comment: Tested link secrets from an Azure key vault as variables in variable group , I was able to successfully [download the secret](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38J19.png) in the pipeline.Can you share your detailed operation steps?This will help further investigation.

Comment: I have added the code snippet in the question. The download of any variable from the Key Vault is not the issue as I have also managed to get and most importantly use other variables. The problem is specific to Subscription value and this value does not have to be within Key Vault. If it is placed in the Variable Group the issue is still present.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[From Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/837681/unable-to-authorize-azure-subscription-for-use-wit.html)

> Thanks for reporting the issue on Developer Community. Azure key vault
>   values are fetched at run time. The resource are authorized before
>   deployment. Pipeline can;t be authorized for a value that is not
>   available. Hence this is not supported. scenario.

Comment: Answers should contain some original content.